# Do different ports on local dynamodb mean that they are different database?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

If I have two node apps (one running on port 1000 and one on 3000) and two dynamodb ports (one running on port 2000 and one on 4000). I want the 1000 port to only talk to the 2000 port and 3000 port to talk to 4000 one. I tried to do this but the data is same for both. A change in one, reflects on the other. Is it like this or is this my fault in some setup? I wish to resolve a concurrency problem in node.js without need of session token (just need a quick solution tbh), just setting up a new instance seemed easy solution.

Tips?

*different database or instance of database. I just don't want concurrency issues. I don't want test A to update the database and test B fails because it expected something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest two alternatives:

- Start both DynamoDB local instances with separate `-dbPath` values. I am assuming that you aren't doing this right now, because of which both your instances must be using one data file.

> If you do not specify this option, the file will be written to the current directory.

- Use the `-inMemory` option, because of which:

> DynamoDB will run in memory, instead of using a database file.

Look at more documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html).